# C incrementing a variable inside a function that's inside the while conditional

Tags: c, pointers

I've implemented atoi function. The first while conditional gives wrong answers while the second while conditional gives me the correct answer (provided I increment the pointer inside the while block ofcourse)

```
while( isdigit(*(str++)) )
while( isdigit(*str) )
```

Why is that?

Shouldn't the first while conditional evaluate 'str' then increment. Then dereference the evaluated address. Then pass it to isdigit?!

Isn't that the same as the second while conditional(as long as it's incremented inside the loop)?

Here's the full code just in case:

```
int atoi(char *str)
{
    int sign, number = 0;

    while( isspace(*str) )
        ++str;

    sign = (*str == '-') ? -1 : 1;

    if(*str == '-' || *str == '+')
        str++;

    //while( isdigit(*(str++)) )
    while( isdigit(*str) )
    {
        number = 10 * number + (*str - '0');
        str++;
    }
    return sign * number;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anatomy of the error: `isdigit(*str++)` tells you if the character pointed at by `str` is a digit, so you decide to iterate the loop to process the character — but `++` advances the pointer *before* you enter the loop's body, so you process the *next* character.

Additionally, as @iharob points out in the comment below, `str` is incremented despite the `isdigit` result, also when the character is not a digit. So the first non-digit character would not be processed by the following code (if there were any).

Potentially same problem with `while(isspace(...))`.

Comment: I am very sorry, just realized why you say *Potentially* you are 100% right. If `isspace()` fails it will leave the pointer incremented anyway.

Comment: To be precise, not 'if `isspace()` fails', but 'if `isspace()` returns `false`'. To 'fail' would mean the function classifies the input character incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't with the `while (isdigit(*str++))` but the fact that at this line

```
number = 10 * number + (*str - '0');
```

`str` is pointing to the next character because you already incremented `str` in the `while` condition.

That's why you can't increment the pointer in the `while` condition. You can however do it in the assignment, leading to the following loop

```
while (isdigit((unsigned char) *str) != 0)
    number = 10 * number + (*str++ - '0');
```

This is an example of a possible implementation

```
#include <ctype.h>

int my_atoi(const char *str)
{
    int sign;
    int number;

    number = 0;

    while (isspace((unsigned char) *str) != 0)
        ++str;

    sign = 1;
    switch (*str)
    {
        case '-':
            sign = -1;
        case '+':
            str++;
            break;
    }

    while (isdigit((unsigned char) *str) != 0)
        number = 10 * number + (*str++ - '0');

    return sign * number;
}
```

Comment: I just realized that `isspace(0)` would return `0` as well as `isdigit(0)`... What was I thinking? I really wonder ...